# Lambda expression to initialize array

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there a way to initialize an array or a collection by using a simple lambda expression?

Something like

```
// What about this?
Person[] persons = new Person[15];
persons = () -> {return new Person()};
```

Or

```
// I know, you need to say how many objects
ArrayList<Person> persons = () -> {return new Person()};
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sure - I don't know how useful it is, but it's certainly doable:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Supplier<Test> supplier = () -> new Test();
        List<Test> list = Stream
            .generate(supplier)
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list.size()); // 10
        // Prints false, showing it really is calling the supplier
        // once per iteration.
        System.out.println(list.get(0) == list.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Or directly .generate(() -> new Test()), just to use the lambda operator requested by OP... would rather use .generate(Test::new).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: Yes, I was only separating out the declaration to show the types involved.

Answer (score 29):

If you already have a pre-allocated array, you can use a lambda expression to populate it using [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) or [`Arrays.parallelSetAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-):

```
Arrays.setAll(persons, i -> new Person()); // i is the array index
```

To create a new array, you can use

```
Person[] persons = IntStream.range(0, 15)  // 15 is the size
    .mapToObj(i -> new Person())
    .toArray(Person[]::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to initialize it using Java 8, you don't really need to use a lambda expression. You can achieve that using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
Stream.of(new Person()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to call the lambda expression multiple times to populate the list - see if my answer makes sense to you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Totally makes sense.

Comment: This will create a list containing a single `Person` instance, thus, it’s a complicated way to do the same as `Collections.singletonList(new Person())`

Comment: @Holger singletonList return an immutable list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: `Collectors.toList()` gives no guarantees about mutability or immutability, so that's not really a point in favor of this answer.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: `Collectors.toList()` returns an *unspecified* list type so you can't assume mutability anyway. Theoretically, it could return exactly the same type for a single-element result. Only if immutability is required, `singletonList` is preferable.

Comment: If immutability is not a problem I'd rather use Collections#nCopies instead of this answer... Still using toCollection we could guarantee a mutable list.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but comparing documentation to Collectors source code, the `toList` method will always create an `ArrayList`. Sure the `collect` implementation of the pipeline could modify the type of the list implementation but you should never end up with an immutable List after using Collectors.toList in one of JDK's standard stream implementation. Considering this, I believe the warning about mutability, serializability etc should be in `Stream#collect` documentation.

Comment: @Jean-François Savard never take the current source code for granted. It can always change at any point, so if you make assumptions based on the current code instead of the documentation, you can introduce bugs once you upgrade to a newer version of the JDK.

Comment: @Ricola agreed. I was a kid back then.