# How to fill 2 dimensional array using Lambda in Java

Tags: java, lambda, foreach

I'am trying to create simple 2 dimensional array of `double`.
Using `for` loop it's not a big deal to make it like:

```
static public double[][] genMatrix(int n) {
    double mat[][]=new double[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            mat[i][j]=generateDouble();
    return mat;
}
```

I'd like to do it smoother with a lambda expression and `forEach` but I'm getting an array full of zeros. Why?

```
private static double[][] genSquareMatrix(int matrixDimension) {
    double matrix[][] = new double[matrixDimension][matrixDimension];
    Arrays.stream(matrix).forEach(x->Arrays.stream(x).forEach(y-> y = generateDouble()));
    return matrix;
}
```

By the way, when I use a lambda to print that array there is no problem.

Comment: This looks promising: [Lambda expression to initialize array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36885371/12323248)

Comment: You are getting only zeros because you don't write anything to your arrays. You just iterate all elements, which are default-initialized to zero, and always overwrite the local variable `y` by `generateDouble`.

Comment: @akuzminykh I wanted it to be shorter then my instructor version at university but now seems like he know what he's doing

Comment: Yes, just keep it simple and use loops in the beginning. The answer that you've accepted is btw. wrong. It addresses a right thing, but doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @akuzminykh Can you explain that further? Java Streams are not modifying their source in any way. Taken from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):


Functional in nature. An operation on a stream produces a result, but does not modify its source. For example, filtering a Stream obtained from a collection produces a new Stream without the filtered elements, rather than removing elements from the source collection.

Comment: Ok, thx for your statement, found my mistake. Cited the false part of docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> Functional in nature. An operation on a stream produces a result, but does not modify its source. For example, filtering a Stream obtained from a collection produces a new Stream without the filtered elements, rather than removing elements from the source collection.

It returns a `DoubleStream`, which supports

> sequential and parallel aggregate operations

This is why it not works.

**Edit:** The first section was incorrect. Replaced it by a more correct version